# Need help with tar.gz files

Tags: files

I know how to unpack a tar.gz file but am clueless when it comes to the next procedure as I opened file install and it opened up in gedit as a installation script, now the question is how do I run it??? What is the next step???
Thanks in advance for your help...
Vektron

Answer (score 1):

That strongly depends on what kind of file was extracted. You should not try to install software from tar.gz since there is no standard way to do that. It is better to try to find the same software in the software center and install it automatically from there.

Having said that, here is what most often works more or less, given that the extracted file is called "install.sh":

```
tar -xf somefile.tgz
chmod +x install.sh
./install.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install an application that way, you should use:

```
sudo tar -xfz file.tar.gz /usr/share
```

That will extract the program to the place, where software is normally placed, when installing through software center.

If you don't want to install an application and just extract something, the way is similar, but you should give a different directory path. Like:

```
tar -xfz file.tar.gz /home/YOUR_USERNAME
```

Comment: ***BAD IDEA!*** The first method only works if it is only a compiled file. If (as it is more likely here) the tar.gz contains source code, extracting it can cause unrepairable damage to your system!